# Lower-dimensional analogues of electroweak interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electroweak

Do there exist any models or theories of the 1+1 dimensional or 2+1 dimensional analogues of the standard 3+1 dimensional electroweak interaction theory?

Comment: I know that people study $1+1$ and $2+1$ dimensional QED. Not sure I can answer, but why are you interested in lower-dimensional versions of electroweak theory?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a process for low-dimensional EW theory? Do you assume that all the proccesses from 3+1 have analogs in lower dimensions?